# How do procedure designers calculate Minimum Enroute Altitudes?

Tags: instrument-procedures, minimum-enroute-altitude, procedure-design

When the designers of instrument flight procedures design a new procedure, I understand that they use certain manuals, such as *ICAO*'s Doc29 or *FAA*'s  TERPS and PBN (8260.58), in order to construct each leg of the procedure by taking into consideration the required obstacle clearance. I can see how one could deduce the Minimum Obstacle Clearance Altitude from the calculated Obstacle Clearance Surface, but how do they know which altitudes, based on each leg of the designed procedure, provide adequate reception of relevant navigation facilities and ATS communications? How do they get that information?